# Most efficient way to delete multiple occurrences of value with CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

If I have multiple documents with an array of tags, what is the most efficient way to delete occurrences of a tag.

Example documents:

```
"name": "doc1",
"tags": ["blue", "pink", "red"]

"name": "doc2",
"tags": ["brown", "pink", "yellow"]
```

If I now wish to delete "pink" from both and all documents, I could loop through each document, and then loop through each array of tags, testing for "pink". But I'm trying to find out if there is a more efficient and/or built in way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a view that emits every tag.

Eg :

```
function(doc){
  for(var tag in docs.tags)
     emit(tag);
}
```

Then, you can query the view by specifying the tag you want to delete the key. Eg: `?key="pink"`

Then, you will have to iterate through all the documents returned, remove pink from the tags and update them all.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I've got already... just wondering if there was a neater / quicker way of doing it? Perhaps not I guess..

Comment: Not really. There's no such thing as bulk update as in SQL database.